# Seq but multiplying by the step instead of adding it

Tags: coreutils

[seq](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#seq-invocation) "*prints a sequence of numbers to standard output*", and, as far as I know, it can only increment the counter by adding.

For instance,

```
seq 0 3 10
0
3
6
9
```

tells `seq` to count from 0 to 10 by increment of 3.

*Is there any way to multiply instead of adding the increment?*

A commend `seq-mult` that would produce

```
seq-mult 1 10 10000
1
10
100
1000
10000
```

Comment: Since `seq` is Open Source, you could download the source and change it.

Comment: Ok, I guess this could be a viable option, but I need this command in a makefile that is shared by multiple users, so it would be a hassle to re-compile the modded utility on each machine.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy to program as a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=$1
while [[ $i -le $3 ]]
do
  printf "%d\n" $i
  (( i *= $2 ))
done
```

Absolutely no error checking done here. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop you could do something like:

```
start=$1
incr=$2
end=$3
for ((i=start;i<=end;i*=incr)); do
  printf '%d\n' "$i"
  ((i==0)) && break
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [doneal24's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697273/101324), I have written my own "recipe", that works inside a makefile, provided `MIN_INPUT`, `MAX_INPUT` and `STEP` have been defined:

```
range=$(MIN_INPUT); \
max=$(MAX_INPUT);\
step=$(STEP);\
while [ $$range -le $$max ];\
    do\
        range=`expr $$range \* $$step`;\
    done
```

Comment: Upvoting this over my own answer since this can be included in the Makefile as the OP wanted (although this need was expressed only in a comment).